# why can't sort 12 elements in 29 comparisons

Tags: information-theory, entropy, sorting

The information theoretic lower bound for sorting 12 elements is using 29 comparisons, but actually we can't sort them in less than 30 comparisons. My problem is that why we can't reach the information theoretic lower bound?
I am looking for an intuitive explanation answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof? (There may be nothing better available than an exhaustive enumeration of possible strategies.) Or for an intuitive explanation of how it is possible that the information-theoretic bound is not always reachable?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am looking for an intuitive explanation since I already know that an exhaustive enumeration of all strategies gives us the 30 as the best answer.

Comment: Can you write something about why you would _expect_ to be able to reach the lower bound?

Comment: @HenningMakholm For n elements, there are $n!$ permutations, so only $n!$ possible results. For each comparison, we gain some information, so the possible results will reduced to half. So $log(n!)$ comparisons will reduce the $n!$ possible results to only one result, which is the sorted outcome. So 12 elements should sorted in $log(12!)=28.83 \sim 29$ comparisons. I think this sounds reasonable. Is there any problem?

Comment: "The information theoretic lower bound for sorting 12 elements is using 29 comparisons" Coud you provide a reference?

Comment: @leonbloy I first know this from my teacher's lecture, so it may be informal. I googled a while, sorry I can't find some formal reference to support it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that intution can help much here. It's true that the number of sortings fits in 29 bits  ($12 ! < 2^{29}$), so it's in principle possible to identify a permutation by making at most 29 yes-no questions. But a comparison algorithm imposes a huge restriction: instead of chossing among all the arbitrary yes-no questions ($2^{11}=2048$ questions) we must restrict to pair comparisons ($ 66$ questions).

In the book [Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++ (Clifford A. Shaffer)](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=AijEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA511&lpg=PA511) it's stated that the claimed result (30 comparisons are needed to sort 12 elements) was proved by brute-force enumeration:

[image]

["A survey of analysis techniques for combinatorial algorithms" Bruce Weide](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3347&context=compsci) 
mentions the paper

> Wells , M.B., "Applications of a language for computing in
>   combinatorics", Proceedings of IFIP Congress 65, vol. 2, 1965,
>   497-498.

as the one which proved that.

Comment: See also [Towards Optimal Sorting of 16 Elements](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0866).

Answer (score 1):

For intuitive explanation it is better to look at a similar problem, but with a more pronounced difference.

Let's look at a task of finding heaviest among $128$ visually identical stones.
Information theory tells us that since the answer is $1$ of $128$ variants we should be able to find it in $log_2(128)=7$ yes/no questions.

Using arbitrary questions - it is indeed the case. You split $128$ stones in two piles of $64$, and ask if the first of them contains the heaviest stone; repeat with the pile containing heaviest stone. After $7$ iterations you are left with the heaviest stone.

Constraining questions to 'is the first of two given stones heavier', you need at least $64$ questions to know at least something about each stone. And since you can not exclude a stone without any information about it from consideration, your lower bound goes up to $64$ questions.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).